# What typeface do you think was used for this:

Tags: font-identification

[image]

Does anyone know what typeface was use for the 'H', 'R', 'A' and 'E' on Short Waves?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Patricia, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. We have a collection of font identification resources [right here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is a good idea to try those first. Please let us know what you have tried without luck. Always good to show a little effort, and chances of getting a good answer increase. Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks very similar to  [Lovelo](http://fontfabric.com/lovelo-font/) font

[image]

Comment: Wow! I think that is definitely the typeface. Thank you so much for your help!